# Responsiveness when device/screen width same but different screen/device width

Tags: html, css

I am facing an issue, lets discuss.

iphone 8 has device width 375px and screen width about 2.300inch. On the other hand, iphone 10 has device width 375px and screen width about 2.456inch. **Same device width but different screen width**.

Let, I set an element's width 100px. So, that element will contain large screen space on iphone 10 than iphone 8. How can I solve this kind of problem in terms of **responsive web design**?

Again, let, I have an imaginary device which has device width **375px** and screen width **8.000inch**. Then what will be the solution?

And, again, what will be the solution if device width **320px** and screen width **2.300inch**?

Thanks in advance.

N.B.: Do I missing something about responsive web design? Then please inform because I am newcomer.

Comment: [Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) here is a great link to review about the issues you are facing. You need to utilize media queries in responsive web design to account for different devices viewing the page

Comment: @BeerusDev Would you please discuss it by your own understanding.

Comment: On both iPhone 8 and iPhone 10, a 100px wide element will take 26.66% (4/15 or 100px/375px) of the total width in full screen mode.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass but physical screen width will different.

Comment: What is yoir concern? You yoirself have just here written they have the same width in pixels. So a pixel is different size in these devices. What concern is it to you in regards to responsive design? Please, these comment sections are not meant for discussion. If the answer has helped you, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a multitude of approaches to responsive webdesign.

Something that we may use to account for different **screen sizes**, **orientations** and **aspect ratios** are **media queries**.
There are different levels of media queries and at level 4, these **Media features** were deprecated:

| Name | Summary | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| device-aspect-ratio | Width-to-height aspect ratio of the output device | Deprecated in Media Queries Level 4. |
| device-height | Height of the rendering surface of the output device | Deprecated in Media Queries Level 4. |
| device-width | Width of the rendering surface of the output device | Deprecated in Media Queries Level 4. |

What is important is the aspect ratio, height and width of the viewport, which is defined in the browser.

With all that explained. When we define media queries, focus is on height and width **measurements** in units such as `px`, `em` and **orientations** such as `portrait` and `landscape`.

These are independent from device sizes in `cm` or `inch`.

Comment: So, I have to dill with Media Queries. Actually no pixel perfect solution because same Media Queries can be applied for different physical screen sizes.

Comment: Media queries are mostly implemented with `px` for width. It is possible to create responsive designs using flexbox and gridsystems completely free from media queries.